# Scroll div that doesn't use overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a not so unique problem I am running into. Currently utilizing the Google Maps API InfoBox. If a specific flag is set on this infobox the scroll is disabled. I need to have this flag set and there seems no way to dynamically change it.

The only way around this may be to use a pure JavaScript scrolling function. The standard CSS would be:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

However this does not function per the flag above. I have also tried a number of JavaScript libraries but they just seem to be pretty versions of the standard CSS scroll.

Does anyone know of a library which uses only JavaScript to scroll inside of a `div`?

answer

```
    function touchScroll(id){
  //  if(isTouchDevice()){ //if touch events exist...
        var el=document.getElementById(id);
        var scrollStartPos=0;

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
            scrollStartPos=this.scrollTop+event.touches[0].pageY;
            event.preventDefault();
        },false);

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
            this.scrollTop=scrollStartPos-event.touches[0].pageY;
            event.preventDefault();
        },false);
  //  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function calls the `isTouchDevice()` function, and if it succeeds a special touch events is attached to the page. First when a touch event begins (the `touchstart` event) it get the current scroll position and prevent the default browser behavior, which in this case would be to scroll the page. Next when a finger is moved  the `touchmove` event is called. Here the position of your finger is subtract from the scroll position that was saved earlier and again prevent the page from scrolling.

```
function isTouchDevice(){
    try{
        document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
        return true;
    }catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

So that’s it, just include these functions on your page and just call it by passing in the `ID` of the element you want to scroll. Like so: `touchScroll("MyElement");`.

[working demo here:](http://chrismbarr.github.com/TouchScroll)

```
function touchScroll(id){
    if(isTouchDevice()){ //if touch events exist...
        var el=document.getElementById(id);
        var scrollStartPos=0;

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
            scrollStartPos=this.scrollTop+event.touches[0].pageY;
            event.preventDefault();
        },false);

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
            this.scrollTop=scrollStartPos-event.touches[0].pageY;
            event.preventDefault();
        },false);
    }
}
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/chrismbarr/4107472#file-istouchdevice-js)

Comment: thank you! I only needed the touchScroll method since this is only going to be accessible from ios browser.